# Python, Numpy: copying single rows to multiple indexes in irregular order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, copy

I have a problem where I need to copy single rows of one matrix to multiple specific rows in a bigger matrix. For example:

```
            Matrix A:
                [row1]
                [row2]
                [row3]
```

Copied to

```
            Matrix B:
                [row3]
                [row3] 
                [row2]
                [row2] 
                [row3] 
                [row1]
```

The values in A may change during execution, but the rows are always copied to B by the same pattern.
I've already tried this:

```
            B = A[3,3,2,2,3,1]
```

But this was even slower than a simple for-loop where I placed the rows one by one. I need to do this as fast as possible with matrix sizes A ≈ (500, 500) and B ≈ (2000, 500).
Does anyone know a more efficient way to do this in python with numpy matrices?

Comment: As I know, the size of the problem i.e. size of the matrices and data volume are very important. In examples by matrices as small size as your wrote example, I guess there will not be a significant difference among methods. It could be seen in comparisons of some methods on SO, the total execution time relating to a method became less than others after some time of the execution; becomes from the worst to the best during the total execution time. In such problems, I recommend using libraries such as numpy, and better than that, jax.

Comment: Did you mean, without using e.g. `A.tolist()` as it is used in @sgs's answer? From `B = A[3,3,2,2,3,1]`, it is understood that counts of each rows in the B could be varied i.e. counts of row3 is not equal with counts of row1 (3 != 1). Is it true or each rows of A is copied in B with same counts?

Comment: Yes the count of rows can be different for every different row in B. I meant that I always copy them to the same position, the pattern of B is consistent during the whole execution. So the counts of certain rows in B also stays the same. Just the Values in A change and I have to repeat this same copy process over and over again.

Comment: Hi @Archaon if any answer has solved your question or was helpful please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark or upvoting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but it looks decently fast

```
%%timeit
A = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
Alist = A.tolist()  
B = np.matrix([Alist[2],Alist[2],Alist[1],Alist[1],Alist[2],Alist[0]])


13.4 µs ± 82.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: The time will be halved by using np.array instead of np.matrix.

Comment: The OP seemed to be willing to use matrix, thats why i kept it

Comment: My explanation was maybe a bit misleading, np.arrays are enough of course. I hope there is a faster way without using standard python list but this already helps, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As it is recommended in the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy-matrix), it is better to use arrays instead of matrices. I have tested the following codes to compare between using arrays and matrices:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
A_arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
A_mat = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
Alist_arr = A_arr.tolist()
Alist_mat = A_mat.tolist()
# using listing
%timeit -n1000 -r5 np.array([Alist_arr[2], Alist_arr[2], Alist_arr[1], Alist_arr[1], Alist_arr[2], Alist_arr[0]])
%timeit -n1000 -r5 np.array([Alist_mat[2], Alist_mat[2], Alist_mat[1], Alist_mat[1], Alist_mat[2], Alist_mat[0]])
%timeit -n1000 -r5 np.matrix([Alist_arr[2], Alist_arr[2], Alist_arr[1], Alist_arr[1], Alist_arr[2], Alist_arr[0]])
%timeit -n1000 -r5 np.matrix([Alist_mat[2], Alist_mat[2], Alist_mat[1], Alist_mat[1], Alist_mat[2], Alist_mat[0]])
# without listing
%timeit -n1000 -r5 np.array([A_arr[2], A_arr[2], A_arr[1], A_arr[1], A_arr[2], A_arr[0]])
%timeit -n1000 -r5 np.array([np.ravel(A_mat[2]), np.ravel(A_mat[2]), np.ravel(A_mat[1]), np.ravel(A_mat[1]), np.ravel(A_mat[2]), np.ravel(A_mat[0])])
%timeit -n1000 -r5 np.matrix([A_arr[2], A_arr[2], A_arr[1], A_arr[1], A_arr[2], A_arr[0]])
%timeit -n1000 -r5 np.matrix([np.ravel(A_mat[2]), np.ravel(A_mat[2]), np.ravel(A_mat[1]), np.ravel(A_mat[1]), np.ravel(A_mat[2]), np.ravel(A_mat[0])])
```

And the following results achieved:

```
1000 loops, best of 5: 6.99 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 7.16 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 13.2 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 13.2 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 4.32 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 38.4 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 11.8 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 48.1 µs per loop
```

The aforementioned results show that using arrays instead of matrices without using listing will have the least execution time. So, I recommend to get B using such the following code:

```
B = np.array([A_arr[2], A_arr[2], A_arr[1], A_arr[1], A_arr[2], A_arr[0]])
```

Hope it could be helpful.